# Multiple updates to table in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a bunch of values I need to change in a column where they match an existing value. For example,

```
 new    old
100001  1001
100004  1004
100005  1005
100011  1011
100022  1022
```

Yes, there is a pattern here, but that pattern breaks further down the list so `substr` won't work throughout.

Anyway, was hoping to do something like the following which I know isn't right:

```
UPDATE table SET field = '100001' WHERE field = '1001',
             SET field = '100002' WHERE field = '1002',
             etc...
```

In quotes because the field is alpha-numeric despite this example just showing integers.

Is there a variation of the above that would work that I am just failing to think of?

Trying to avoid the import, join, rename if possible.

Comment: what is the real pattern?

Comment: Based on your sample data, substr will work. Please post sample data where you think it won’t.

Comment: @Randy There isn't a real pattern. The first few I grabbed from the list there is, but about 200 in it starts becoming random and it is like that for the next several thousand.

Comment: For the ones with a pattern, you can update in batch with a where clause. For those without a pattern, you just have to do them one by one

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ok, kind of what I figured, but wanted to bounce the idea of some other people for fresh insight. Already started doing a import, join, update anyway.

Comment: is there anything else that the two have in common, another field? ordinal position in the list?

Comment: You can use a custom VBA function, which returns new field value using old value as parameter, but join will work faster

Comment: Note that you likely don't have to import. You can join external files (like excel files, CSVs, other access databases) without importing them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the answer is no, the above will not work. I just created a new table to upload the New and Old codes into and inserted a column into the table I wanted to update with the new code.

Then I did a `JOIN` in my `UPDATE` to read in the new code into the table, then from their did an update where the code was `NOT NULL`. Basically a few steps, but it sounds like there might be better ways in the comments.

```
UPDATE table1 AS c INNER JOIN table2 AS n ON c.Code=n.OldCode SET c.NewCode = n.NewCode
WHERE c.Client= 175;
```

Then...

```
UPDATE table1 SET Code = NewCode
WHERE Client = 175 AND NewCode IS NOT NULL;
```